# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `MovieResults`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can not go to the Move.js page to page Details.js

I do not understand why I have this response : Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `MovieResults`

Movie.js :

```
var Movie = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var link = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + this.props.movie.imdbID;
        var myLink = 'search/' + this.props.movie.imdbID;

        return(
            <div className="well">
                <div className="row">
                    <h4 className="text-center">
                        <Link to={myLink} activeClassName="current">{this.props.movie.Title}</Link>
                    </h4>
                </div>


            </div>    
        )
    },
});
```

Details.js :

```
var Details = React.createClass({
    render: function(){

        var link = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + this.props.movie.imdbID;

        var title = this.props.movie.Title;
        var year = this.props.movie.Year;
        var type = this.props.movie.Type;
        var poster = this.props.movie.Poster;
        var imdbID = this.props.movie.imdbID;

        return(
            <div className="well">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img className="thumbnail" src={poster} /> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <h4><a href={this.props.movie.Title}> {title}</a></h4>
                        <ul className="padding">
                            <li className="list-group-item">Type : {type}</li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">Year Released : {year}</li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">Id imdb : {imdbID}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <a className="btn btn-primary" href={link}>View on IMDB</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Movie movie={this.props.Details} key={i} />
            </div>    
        )
    },
});
```

Comment: Could you show the `MovieResults` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DOCS**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

> The key should always be supplied directly to the components in the
>   array, not to the container HTML child of each component in the array

So... Add **key** attribute to the first child `<div>`

```
var MovieResults = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h3 className="text-center"> Results </h3>
        {
          this.props.movies.map(function(movie, i){
            return(
              <div key={i}>
                <Movie movie={movie}/>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>    
    )
  }
})
```